# Sequence diagram should consist of View objects, DB objects, etc.?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

What is the correct usage of UML sequence diagrams? Should they contain objects of View classes or DB classes? Or should they modeled in a more generalized fashion? Or is this completely arbitrary?

Answer (score 2):

It should contain the objects of interest in the interaction.

Like any type of documentation, it should focus on what you are trying to document. If you are documenting the DB interaction, you should have the DB classes involved. If not, you shouldn't.

Comment: Okay. So what should I do if I draw a diagram for "User logging" and I want to point out displaying a login form? Should I return directly from an User class the message, or return the form from the UserView class?

Comment: @daroPL - What are you trying to document for "User logging"? Validation? Interactions with the database? Who is the audience for this?

Comment: I based on the use cases, an actor is an User. At first the User run the Login option, next the System (an User or UserView class) displays the login form, after that the User input the data. System verify the data by checking it in the database. Finally, it displays a message "You are logged now".

Comment: Maybe it should be like "User (an actor) <-> User (object) <-> DB, where DB is some kind of generalized object, which consist of different Model Classes within real code?

Comment: @daroPL - It really depends on who the audience of the document is and what you are trying to convey to them.

Comment: Hmmm... the audience are project`s programmers. It's my first project I would like to design in UML, so I please mainly about general directions what's wrong. I did some diagram here http://imageshack.us/f/210/employeelogin.png/